# Какую JAVA использовать для Android?

Tags: java, android

Какую JAVA использовать для Android: x86 или x64 и в чем разница?

Comment: Это зависит от разрядности ОС на компьютере, где вы компилируете apk из исходного кода. Для Android и скомпилированного apk нет никакой разницы, какой разрядности была Java при сборке.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Приколов нет. Используйте ту java, которая подходит для Вашей хостовой машины. x86 подойдет практически для любой машины (и для 32 и для 64 битных). x64 - только для 64 операционных систем. Какое то время назад x64 была не такой "устойчивой", как x86 и многие рекомендовали использовать только x86. На данный момент все достаточно стабильно.

Когда Ваше приложение компилируется, то оно превращается в байт код, который не зависит (не должен зависеть) от того, какая версия x86 или x64 на хостовой машине.

Поэтому, так как у Вас скорее всего установленна 64битная ОС, пробуйте x64 (она же amd64). Если все установиться и будет работать, значит пусть работает.

Comment: байт-код не зависит не только от разрядности машины, но даже и от архитектуры процессора, установленной ОС и тп. Единственное, что требуется - компилятор Java на этой машине.

Comment: байт код зависит только от целевой системы. А вот какой именно байт код будет сгенерирован, зависит от компилятора. В теории, для одного и того же java кода компиляторами различной битности должен быть сгенерирован абсолютно один и тот же байт-код.

Comment: Я об этом и говорю - нет вообще никакой разницы, где компилировалось, если есть компилятор на машине назначения, то код будет работать. Я просто к тому, что вы написали *"не должен зависеть"* - байт-код абсолютно точно не зависит от разрядности машины на которой его компилировали.

Comment: под словом байткод понимаются две сущности. Первое - это система команд виртуальной машины. А она зависит только от версии виртуальной машины и не зависит от целевой платформы и разрядности компилятора. Второе - это скомпилированный бинарник (обычно это файл с расширением class). И вот он может отличаться, если скомпилировать разными компиляторами (разной разрядности). Но он обязан быть "эквивалентным".